# How to return table row to existing variable?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, return, store

I am trying to get data from transitions table and store in $tableData variable.

```
$tableData = getTableData();
```

This function will get first row of the transitions table.

```
table data : Array
(
 [id] => 1
 [name] => S1
 [active] => True
 [from_loc] => start
 [to_loc] => check_owner
 [guard] => own==0 && contract_start==0
 [sync] => 
 [assignment] => contractStart(),own=1,contract_start=1,contract_end=0
 [checked] => 0
)
```

I wanna do something like. If guard is not empty get next row.
Here is my code:

```
$tableData = getTableData();
$id = $tableData['id'];
$name = $tableData['name'];
$active = $tableData['active'];
$from_loc = $tableData['from_loc'];
$to_loc = $tableData['to_loc'];
$guard = $tableData['guard'];
$sync = $tableData['sync'];
$assignment = $tableData['assignment'];

if (!empty($guard)){
    //get next row with $to_loc
    $tableData = workWithoutSync($id,$to_loc);
//it's getting next row from table and i wanna replace $tableData with this new row 
}else{
// get data from table where id is for example 5 and store in $tableData.
}
```

I just wanna store new data in $tableData and check the conditions again to avoid repetition of code.
any idea?

Comment: Hi Abbas, why don't you use $_GET to get the next row ? (like step by step)

Comment: @Mohsen Sir I am getting data from transitions table and sorry but i didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: you said > I wanna do something like. If guard is not empty get next row. e.g. `index.php?step=1` get tableData `if (!empty($guard))` then go to `index.php?step=2` or you can save them in the database or you can use form method GET or using `header()`

Comment: I said I wanna override $tableData variable every time when i get data from table. Just wanna know how can I override $tableData?